# Set up Custom Domain in Salesforce with GoDaddy Domain

Tags: force.com, custom-domain

I am trying to set up my Godaddy domain name so I can use it in salesforce to create community portals with. I am not sure how I am suppose to set up the Cname to ensure that the domain name can be picked up in salesforce set up.

In GoDaddy I have the name set up to our salesforce domain name which is admagic.force.com and the value is the domain name. When the domain name is put I get the "@" symbol taking it's place. Screenshot below

[image: Godaddy Set up]

When I try to set it up in salesforce I'm getting this error:

Error: Salesforce.com can't validate the domain. The CNAME record may still be processing (which can take up to 24 hours), or the domain may not belong to you. Make sure the domain name logisticscenter.online.00dj0000001nz89eae.live.siteforce.com uses logisticscenter.online.00dj0000001nz89eae.live.siteforce.com.00dj0000001nz89eae.live.siteforce.com as its CNAME target and try again later.

It's been days since this is has been set up on the Godaddy side here is a screenshot of the error in salesforce:

[image: Domain Error]

What steps do I have to do to resolve this?

[image: Godaddy error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a site domain that you have bought using go daddy. Let's say it is [www.mydomaim.com](http://www.mydomaim.com)

When you will try to add this to Salesforce it will error out and give you the CNAME. Now you need to add that CNAME in godaddy settings.

Once that is done it will be propagated to DNS servers all over the world.

After that goto Salesforce and add you custom domain again. This time it should get added. You may need to wait for upto 24 hours.

Then Click in activate. Open the domain in Salesforce and add your community in custom URL below.

Here is how CName will look like.

[image]

**Example Steps:**

In my case, I wanted my community to be available at `https://utilities.manjitsingh.dev`

1. I tried adding `utilities.manjitsingh.dev` in Salesforce which gave me an error saying Make sure the domain name `utilities.manjitsingh.dev` uses `utilities.manjitsingh.dev.00dj0000001nz89eae.live.siteforce.com`.
2. Click cancel then navigate over to my provider and added CNAME as shown in above picture.

- Name = `utilities`. (In you case it will be `www`)
- CNAME = `utilities.manjitsingh.dev.00dj0000001nz89eae.live.siteforce.com`
- TTL = 1m (minute)

Clicked add.

3. Waited for 1 hour.
4. Went back to salesforce and added the domain again. It saves as the CNAME has propagated everywhere.
5. Wait for Activate button to be enabled and then activated and attached the community in Custom URL's.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying,

So I followed that and I still get an error. When setting up the Cname in godaddy what should the host name be? I'm putting my salesforce instance domain name as the host.

Should I use a different host name?

Comment: @LenCadet I added some example steps.

Comment: I'm sure if I posted my picture in the best way but I have a screen shot showing that I get an error when putting www when updating my Cname

Comment: I see that you already have a CNAME defined for www, third line in your first screenshot. You should try removing it and then adding a new one. If the error persists you may need to contact GoDaddy support.

Comment: Yeah that part you put was correct. I updated the cname with the www has the name and the correct value and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Steps to create the custom domain are as follow as

1. Create the CA-Signed Certificate from Salesforce
2. Upload the Signed Certificate:
3. Add a domain
4. Custom URL if needed

https://forcewizard.blogspot.com/2022/07/adding-custom-domain.html

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Link-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/380975/edit) your answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*